# "Moving" from one class to another in Python

Tags: python, oop

So, I have this problem I'm working on, and if someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be so grateful. Let me set it up for you.

I have 1 Python file/module named rooms filled with classes, like so:

```
class Intro(object):

    def __init__(self):
         # Setting up some variables here

    def description(self):
        print "Here is the description of the room you are in"
```

Which is all cool and stuff right? Then on another file/module, named Engine. I have this:

```
import rooms

class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, first_class):
        self.lvl = first_class

    def play_it(self):
        next_lvl = self.lvl

        while True:
            # Get the class we're in & run its description
            next_lvl.description() # it works.
            # But how do I get the next class when this class is done?
```

See what I would like to happen is based on the user's decision within each room/level class, the engine call upon a new class w/ its description function/attribute. Does that make sense? Or is there another way I should be thinking about this? Im ass-backwards sometimes. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegate the choice of which class to use next into the rooms.  Eg

```
class Intro(object):

    def __init__(self):
         # Setting up some variables here

    def description(self):
        print "Here is the description of the room you are in"

    def north(self):
        return Dungeon()

    def west(self):
        return Outside()

    #etc
```

So when the player says "go west" in the Intro room, the Engine calls `room.west()` and the `Intro` room returns the `Outside` room.

Hopefully that is enough of a hint! I expect you'll want to make your own design.